# Rails 5 - How to solve HTTP 403 response body error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, docker, certificate

I am trying to run a rails 5 project with the docker container and front-end is reactjs. While running a `sudo bin/houston start` command I am getting an error like

```
Firing engines...
Pulling elasticsearch (docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0)...
ERROR: error parsing HTTP 403 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<meta name=\"referrer\" content=\"no-referrer\">\n    <title>Web Filter Violation</title>\n    <style type=\"text/css\">\n        html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; }\n        h1, h2 { height: 82px; text-indent: -999em; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; }\n        div { margin: 0; padding: 0; }\n        div.header { background: url(http://url.fortinet.net:8008/XX/YY/ZZ/CI/MGPGHGPGPFGHCDPFGGOGFGEH) 0 0 repeat-x; height: 82px; }\n        div.header h1 { background: url(http://url.fortinet.net:8008/XX/YY/ZZ/CI/MGPGHGPGPFGHCDPFGGHGFHBGCHEGPFHHGG) 0 0 no-repeat; }\n        div.header h2 { background: url(http://url.fortinet.net:8008/XX/YY/ZZ/CI/MGPGHGPGPFGHCDPFGGOGFGEH) 0 -82px no-repeat; width: 160px; float: right; }\n        div.sidebar { width: 195px; height: 200px; float: left; }\n        div.main { padding: 5px; margin-left: 195px; }\n        div.buttons { margin-top: 30px; text-align: right; }\n        h3 { margin: 36px 0; font-size: 16pt; }\n        .blocked      h3 { color: #c00; }\n        .authenticate h3 { color: #36c; }\n        h2.fgd_icon { background: url(http://url.fortinet.net:8008/XX/YY/ZZ/CI/MGPGHGPGPFGHCDPFGGOGFGEH) 0 -166px repeat-x; width: 90px; height: 92px; margin: 48px auto; }\n        .blocked      h2.fgd_icon { background-position: 0 -166px; }\n        .authenticate h2.fgd_icon { background-position: -89px -166px; }\n        form { width: 300px; margin: 30px 0; }\n        label { display: block; width: 300px; margin: 5px 0; line-height: 25px; }\n        label input { width: 200px; border: 1px solid #7f9db9; height: 20px; float: right; }\n    </style>\n</head>\n<body class=\"blocked\">\n    <div class=\"header\">\n        <h2>Powered By Fortinet</h2>\n        <h1>FortiGuard Web Filtering</h1>\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"sidebar\">\n        <h2 class=\"fgd_icon\">blocked</h2>\n    </div>\n    <div class=\"main\">\n<h3>Web Page Blocked!</h3>\n<div class=\"notice\">\n    <p>You have tried to access a web page which is in violation of your internet usage policy.</p>\n    <p>\n        URL: https://docker.elastic.co/<br />\n        Category: Business\n        <br/>Client IP: 172.16.3.74\n        <br/>Server IP: 52.206.9.114\n        <br/>User name: \n        <br/>Group name: \n    </p>\n    <p>\n       \n    </p>\n    <p> To have the rating of this web page re-evaluated <a href=\"http://url.fortinet.net/rate/submit.php?id=4F023F7369116F493E247B733E653336&cat=31&loc=https://docker%2eelastic%2eco%2f&ver=8\">please click here</a>.</p>\n</div>\n    </div>\n</body>\n</html>\r\n"
```

If I try to solve by running other commands and I will get `CA Certification` error.

If I run `sudo bin/houston bundle` then the error is like `ERROR: No container found for web_1`

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue opened in docker-registry github repository and it seems very similar to your bug.

Check it out:
https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/298